# Influenza viruses

Tags: biology, viruses

Suppose the H7N9 virus becomes pandemic; know that it has a 60% mortality rate. Suppose a vaccine has been developed that has a 1/100,000 chance of causing permanent paralysis of your legs. Is it feasible to be vaccinated or not? Why?

Note: 60% is an average much more or less, of the two H7N9 outbreaks that we had in China, one had a mortality rate above 80%. But epidemiology has wonderful statistical tools that have thrown the real number we found in China down: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6595816/

The two outbreaks (and the only ones) that occurred in China had mortality in excess of 60%, I repeat, both. But why did it go down to 60%? Well, epidemiology is not a pub science, it has tools that allow you to consider modeling on a global scale what only happened on a local scale, when this was done for H7N9 the mortality went down

**Edited**: I didn't put prevalence/morbidity rate because H7N9 hasn't become pandemic until now precisely because it has a low transmissibility rate **when compared to other members of the Orthomyxoviridae family**. However, it is only a matter of time before it undergoes a mutation that favors transmissibility, and as this is a future mutagenic event, it is not possible to determine with certainty. What I can tell you, however, is that all the viruses in the Orthomyxoviridae family that went through one or a sequence of mutations that favored transmissibility ended up having the highest transmissibility rates among all existing viruses. The top 8 of the most transmissible viruses in the world are all from the same family as H7N9, positions 10, 11 and 12 are also occupied by them. To make the poll question more satisfying for you, then imagine that H7N9 undergoes a sequence of mutations that make it 2x times contagious than the current SARS-CoV-2 (this is a conservative number, since, to this day, all Viruses of the Orthomyxoviridae family that have become pandemic enjoy a higher transmissibility rate than any virus of the Coronaviridae family).

https://www.who.int/influenza/human_animal_interface/influenza_h7n9/en/

The reason why so many new viruses are emerging, more specifically since 1996, is multifactorial and has absolutely nothing to do with genetic engineering. The first reason is that 1996 was the year that a global viral observation network was formed, before the data was not integrated, now if a new virus appears in the end of Tanzania or in the middle of New York the data will all be integrated. in the Global Viral Surveillance Network. That alone adds to the feeling that more viruses are emerging.

The point, however, is that in recent years the number of new viruses is actually increasing, and the cause is indeed anthropogenic, but, as I said earlier, it has nothing to do with genetic engineering. Viruses have existed on this planet since before the formation of multicellular life, there is no doubt that they do not need to be created to be so present in our lives. Below, I'll forward a message that I sent to someone else in another group when she asked me why so many new viruses are emerging specifically in China. In this answer I gave her, I commented on the current anthropogenic factor that is responsible for the increasingly frequent generation of new viruses.

Most of the human viruses (+ than 50%) all came from the African continent, not Asia. All diseases that we have in Brazil transmitted by Aedes aegypti, for example, came from there.

What came out of Asia that became a pandemic until today was only the viruses of the coronavirus family (MERS and SARS) and influenza viruses, of the HxNy family.

I would like someone to answer my question

Comment: Unless the question is edited to include a number for prevalence / morbity no answer can be given. That is, 60% mortality rate is once a person is infected; but we need to know what is the chance for a person to be infected in the first place. For example, Ebola has a very high mortality rate, but I wouldn't even consider getting vaccinated against Ebola given that my chances of getting it in the first place are very very close to zero.

Comment: @AlexP I improved my question

Comment: @AlexP Also, H7N9 is not pandemic yet. So why is it considered potentially the most dangerous virus in the world? Ebola.

Comment: It also has a mortality rate close to that of H7N9 but has no chance of joining the list of potentially most dangerous viruses. Because?

Comment: Due to the factor "probability of being benefited from a mutation that results in favoring transmissibility". In other words, H7N9 is barely transmissible right now, but knowing his family as we do, we know he has a very high chance of being favored at any time with high transmissibility. Unlike Ebola, this one can even undergo mutations that make it more lethal, but, knowing its family as we know it, the chance that it will benefit from high transmissibility is low, so it is not part of the "Purple List" like the H7N9.

Comment: No rapid-onset disease with a 60% mortality rate will be able to become pandemic in the modern world. This is why, for example, Ebola keeps on appearing, scaring everyone, and then fading away at/near the source. It is too successful. For a disease to be able to go pandemic, it needs either very low mortality rate (like covid) or very slow onset (like hiv). otherwise people just die where they get the bug, and it fails to spread.

Comment: @PcMan So much is it possible that the H7N9 is on the "Purple List". He is the only virus with more than 15% mortality on this list. So, really, viruses with a high mortality rate are difficult to become pandemic, there is only one exception, the H7N9

Comment: To enter the list, you need to fulfill a number of requirements (more than 80). Ebola, for example, fills 2 or 3. H7N9 is the only virus in the world that we know of with the possibility of integrating high transmissibility + long incubation period

Comment: Your question starts with a lie in the very first sentence, "*know that it has a 60% mortality rate*" and goes downhill from there on.

Comment: @PcMan I edited my post. See if it's acceptable. If I wanted to be sensationalist, I would just take the isolated mortalities, since both are above 60%, but I took the lowest number, and therefore safe, available

Comment: @LockyPauk china only: Total cases so far: 1568. Fatalities: 616. That's a mortality rate of 39%.. that's according to the WHO (World Health Organization) of 27 may 2021, for all cases since the initial identification of this strain in 2013. So, you are accusing the WHO of fraudulent reporting? Or are you admitting to mistruth by yourself?  https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/wpro---documents/emergency/surveillance/avian-influenza/ai-20210528.pdf?sfvrsn=30d65594_137

Comment: @LockyPauk note that case count is for lab-confirmed cases. It is the absolute highest ceiling number possible. Actual figures are magnitudes lower, as some 98% of people that get the virus, are asymptomatic. And of the symptomatic, roughly 85% recovered without ever seeing a doctor) (serology testing of actual population infection fatality risk for H7N9 is 0.036%, so far). Meaning of those exposed to the virus, 360 out of a million died.

Comment: @LockyPauk just for you info. That source you quote for mortality is for "*mortality of **hospitalized** avian influenza A (H7N9)*"... i.e. those who not only were exposed to the virus, AND developed symptoms, AND went to a doctor AND subsequently got so sick that they were hospitalized AND got into the ICU unit of the hospital, 80% died. That is not what mortality rate of a disease is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126157/discussion-between-lockypauk-and-pcman).